# Проблема при подключении ChatGPT в телеграмм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я хочу подключить ChatGPT в телеграмм бота. Сначала подключил модель curie и всё работало, но после я захотел подключить gpt-3.5-turbo. Тут и возникла проблема при задаче вопроса. Не понимаю в чём ошибка.

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import openai
import telebot
import os

bot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT KEY')
model="gpt-3.5-turbo"

openai.api_key = "API KEY"
def ask(prompt):
     completion = openai.Completion.create(engine="/v1/chat/completions", 
                                      prompt=prompt, 
                                      temperature=0.5, 
                                      max_tokens=1000)
     print( 'Вопрос:', prompt )
     print( '\nОтвет:' )
     answer = ( completion.choices[0]['text'] )
     return answer
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, ask(str(message.text)))
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте [API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/introduction), он отличается от API для GPT-3.
Вы должны использовать «messages» вместо «prompt».

```
openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
  ]
)
```

Ответ будет в `response['choices'][0]['message']['content']`